# Get return variable or variable from one function to another function in controller

Tags: codeigniter

I am wondering if it is allowed to access/get/use the variable from one function to another function within one controller?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this.

```
class Index extends CI_Controller {
    protected $var1;

    public function index() {
        $this->setVar1();
        echo $this->var1; // print $var1
    }

    public function setVar1() {
        $this->var1 = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$superduper = 'superduper' ;
```

available only locally within the method (function)
or passed like

```
$this->reviews->insertToReviews($superduper) ;
```

***versus***

```
$this->superduper = 'superduper' ;
```

as soon as $this->variablename is declared in a controller its instantly available to:

- any method in the controller
- any method in any model that is called by the controller
- any view file called by the controller

so without passing the variable - in a view you can use

```
echo 'my lunch is ' . $this->superduper ;
```

but often its better to explicitly pass values to the view especially if they are unique to the method - it makes it easier to see what is going on. so in that case in controller:

```
$data['superduper'] = $this->superduper ;
```

and in view

```
 echo 'my lunch is ' . $superduper ;
```

Now when anyone looks at the method in the controller  - we can see that superduper is being passed to $data. the point is that even though you can avoid passing variable names to methods or the view by declaring $this->somename - if you pass them locally it can make it easier to see what is going on.

The flip side is something like:

```
$this->error_message = "Error retrieving database records";
```

is awesome. you can have error messages in any method and they will be automatically available no matter what else happens. so then in your view file have something like

```
if($this->error_message != '') { echo $this->error_message ;}
```

this is especially helpful while you are building the site.